# Google firebase authentication multiple times

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If an App tries Google firebase login a few times (5 in a few min ?) they are blocked out due to suspicious activity and can resume later on. Our app provides login/logout. Is there a way to avoid this ? Also how long is the lock affected.

Comment: Have you found out how long the user is locked?

Answer (score 1):

There are no mechanisms provided to change the detection and enforcement of suspicious behavior.  Feel free to reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly to make suggestions or send feedback.